# Laravel Update Method Error

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

i have a method to update image path to data base but i'm getting this error

```
ErrorException in DriversController.php line 296:
Attempt to assign property of non-object
```

in my controller

```
public function updateDriver(Request $request, $id)
{
    $driver = Driver::find($id)->update($request->all());

    if($request->hasFile('profile-photo')) {

            $image_file = $request->file('profile-photo');

            $get_image_name = $request['first_name'].$request['phone_number'].'.'.$image_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $get_image_name);

            $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
            $filePath = '/drivers/' . $image_name;
            $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image_file), 'public');

            $driver->profile_photo = $image_name;   //this is ware the error line 296 
            $driver->save();
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Driver updater successfully');
}
```

Thank you

Comment: And line 296 is where in this 22 lines of code?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  thanks for your time, the line is `$driver->profile_photo = $image_name;`

Comment: can you post the output of print_r($driver)?

Comment: `$driver = Driver::find($id)->update($request->all());` this line failed.. you `$driver` variable is `null` or `false`.. that's why you can't assign anything to it..

Comment: Probably you need somthing like `->update($request->except(['_token', 'profile-photo']))`

Comment: @Matei Mihai  @Exprator   Thanks for your time,  the result of ` print_r($driver)` is `1` and `dd($driver)` is `true` and `dd($image_name)` is `image_name.jpg`, i'm not sure why i'm getting this error

Comment: $driver->profile_photo? how will you get it? as there is no object thus that error.

use something like this by removing these two lines
$driver->profile_photo = $image_name;  
$driver->save();

to this 

$driver = Driver::find($id)->update(array('profile_photo'=>$image_name));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your code like :

```
public function updateDriver(Request $request, $id)
{
    $driver = Driver::find($id)->update($request->all());

   if($request->hasFile('profile-photo')) {

           $image_file = $request->file('profile-photo');

           $get_image_name = $request['first_name'].$request['phone_number'].'.'.$image_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $get_image_name);

           $s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
            $filePath = '/drivers/' . $image_name;
            $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image_file), 'public');

           $driver = Driver::find($id)->update(array('profile_photo'=>$image_name));

   }

   return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Driver updater successfully');
}
```

Comment: thank you for your time really appreciate it, it worked

Answer (score 2):

$driver will be a Boolean (I believe) after the update.

Try:

```
$driver = Driver::find($id);
$driver->update($request->all());
```